# how .htaccess to redirect file to another directory if file doesn't exists

Tags: .htaccess

I'm planning to backup my files to another directory, is it possible to make an .htaccess to redirect a file(when not found) to my new directory?

example : `example.com/files/filename.txt` redirects to `example.com/backup/files/filename.txt`

i also want it just for a specific directory, ex. `example.com/files/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to backup/files folder if matches in Files folder
    RewriteRule ^files/(.*)/?$ backup/files/$1 [NC,L]
```